# CRA/React.js/Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM): Web Push notifications are not working when browser is not open

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, create-react-app, service-worker

I am posting this after hours of trawling old StackOverflow,Linkedin and dev.to links.

I am trying to build a React PWA. I have used create-react-app(CRA) v5.0.1 to create my React Application, which also came with a predefined service worker.

In this PWA, one of the main features is the chat function, and new notifications alerting the user that they have new messages.

I chose to use Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) as I was already using a few other Firebase Offerings for my chat and data storage purposes. Thus,I first followed this link to deploy a Cloud Function which will trigger on any new writes to the specific path of the various chat rooms, which then send a payload to the targeted FCM registration token of the specific device.

My payload looks like this:

```
const payload = {
            data: {
                title: `${senderDisplayName} replied to you`,
                body: newMessageText,
                // icon: follower.photoURL
            }
        };

        tokens = Object.keys(tokensSnapshot.val());
        const tokensToRemove: any[] = [];

        // Send individual messages to each token.
        const sendPromises = tokens.map((token) => {
            const message = {
                token: token,
                ...payload
            };
```

This was done mostly following this [guide](https://blog.logrocket.com/push-notifications-react-firebase/) and [GitHub repository](https://github.com/kokanek/firebase-react-notifications). Note that the code segments in the guide seems to be altered and not ideal. It is probably better to reference the code in the repo instead.

I also changed the implementation for onBackgroundMessage to avoid receiving double notifications following this [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66697332/firebase-web-push-notifications-is-triggered-twice-when-using-onbackgroundmessag), which states from [FCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages):
*Use notification messages when you want FCM to handle displaying a notification on your client app's behalf. Use data messages when you want to process the messages on your client app. FCM can send a notification message including an optional data payload. In such cases, FCM handles displaying the notification payload, and the client app handles the data payload.*

```
// Scripts for firebase and firebase messaging
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.0/firebase-app-compat.js");
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.0.0/firebase-messaging-compat.js")


// Initialize the Firebase app in the service worker by passing in
// your app's Firebase config object.
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#config-object
firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: "...",
    authDomain: "...",
    projectId: "...",
    storageBucket: "...",
    messagingSenderId: "...",
    appId: "...",
    measurementId: "....",
    databaseURL:'...',
});

// Retrieve an instance of Firebase Messaging so that it can handle background
// messages.
const messaging = firebase.messaging();

messaging.onBackgroundMessage(function(payload) {
    console.log('Received background message ', payload);

   //const notificationTitle = payload.notification.title;
   //const notificationOptions = {body: payload.notification.body,};

    const notificationTitle = payload.data['title'];
    const notificationOptions = {
        body: payload.data['body'],
    };

    self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle,
        notificationOptions);
});
```

Then, instead of using the service worker provided by CRA, as the Firebase docs recommended creating a firebase-messaging-sw.js file in the public folder, I did just that.

To work around this, I followed this [guide on Linkedin](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/cra-workbox-firebase-cloud-messaging-all-together-solved-zecevic/), where the author recommends *not registering* the predefined service worker and registering the custom firebase-messaging-sw.js in the index.js or whatever your entry point is.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App.tsx';

import * as serviceWorkerRegistration from './serviceWorkerRegistration';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

if ('serviceWorker' in navigator && process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    console.log('Trying to register custom sw');
    navigator.serviceWorker
        .register('./firebase-messaging-sw.js')
        .then(function (registration) {
            console.log('Registration successful, scope is:', registration.scope);
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log('Service worker registration failed, error:', err);
        });
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(<App/>);

// serviceWorkerRegistration.register();
```

Now, I am able to receive background notifications on:

1. Chrome on Windows 10 , when the Chrome Browser is open and the webapp/website is not the active tab
2. Chrome on Android, when the Chrome Browser App is active (aka I am using it) and the webapp/website is not the active tab, PWA not installed
3. Chrome on Android, when the Chrome Browser App is active (aka I am using it) and the website is not open, PWA is installed

When the Chrome Browser App is not active, and I open it, the most recent notifications will be received and displayed on the notification bar on my Android device.

This is all tested on the development server, aka `yarn start` as well as making a production build and serving it using serve

```
yarn build
yarn global add serve
npx serve -s build
```

I have also used [Loophole](https://loophole.cloud/) as a way to test it remotely on my physical Android device as service workers only run over HTTPS, for security reasons.

My question is, how do I receive notifications when the PWA is installed and the Chrome Browser App is not active/open? It seems like the service worker is not running even when the PWA is installed on my Android device. Is there something missing in my implementation process? I would love to have anyone share their knowledge on this matter.

Update 1: Updating the import scripts to match my foreground Firebase package version seems to have solved the issue.

```
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.21.0/firebase-app-compat.js");
importScripts("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.21.0/firebase-messaging-compat.js")
```

Update 2: After restarting the Android device it reverts back to the original behavior

Update 3: After trying a [Simple Web Push demo](https://simple-push-demo.vercel.app/), it seems like it may be a problem with my Android device as the demo also only receive notifications when it is active/in the foreground.

Update 4: Background notifications are working again. Not sure what is causing the issue, perhaps someone can shed some light on how to debug?